# +1 for the name?

Tags: discussion, up-votes

I usually upvote because of the content. But it looks like the [name matters as well](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15025944/1493698) because this comment suggests that the answer was upvoted purely because of the users name, not the content of their answer. Is this type of upvote appropriate?

[image]

Comment: Is there a question here, or did you just feel like sharing?

Comment: @Oded I am sorry I don't quite get it. I think we should go for the content instead of the _name_?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to achieve here - that's what I mean.

Comment: Yeah, I've gotten those before. Also, side note: holy crap, he's back.  I thought I felt a disturbance in the force.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - Watch out for the shrapnel.

Comment: You considered that it was a joke?

Comment: *"I think we should go for the content instead of the name?"* .. absolutely. After all, reputation is a rough indication of how much the community likes your name.

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby No joke intended. I am just asking. I like his answer, but I don't think upvoting for the name is appropriate.

Comment: No, did you consider that Christian Varga was making a joke?

Comment: A JOKE? On The Internet? No, no, such things woudln't be allowed here.

Comment: I think the answer is not even strictly correct, but that's just me :)

Comment: @tombull89 Are you being serious here, or are you kidding? I sure hope it's the former, because the latter wouldn't be allowed here....wait...ehm...

Comment: @Jack: I think the question should be burned...multiple times...

Comment: @Antony "Is this type of upvote appropriate?" ... any user is free to use his votes as he sees fit, as long as it does not fall under such fraudulent behavior as serial upvotes or downvotes. Assuming the user is entirely serious for now, there is not much that can nor should be done.

Comment: Internet is SRS bizness (I was being sarcastic)

Comment: I *dare* someone to add "-1 because I don't like you and you scare me".  I'll be getting the popcorn.

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables Hoping for shrapnel are we?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables don't know the history of the guy - 20 upvotes on this comment and I'll do it.

Comment: @tombull89: I know the guy's history: Please do it!

Comment: -10 on this post because I lack common sense.

Comment: @Bart I *just* got that reference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It was likely a joke.

And even if it wasn't, everyone is free to vote as they please on Stack Overflow; it's one of the few actions that cannot be reviewed or changed, not even by a moderator.

Comment: -1 because I'm still waiting for my handbags.

Comment: @Bart they were delivered. I have a signed receipt somewhere. (Don't ask me to produce it though, I don't know where it is)

Comment: +1 because I'm gullible

Comment: @Bart in fact, I have *two* signed receipts here so technically, you still owe me money for the order. (Pushing my luck here, but who dares wins!)

Comment: +1 because cheesecakes.

Comment: @Pekka웃 I have a reserved sum of money for you in my bank account. Unfortunately this has been locked by the bank. If you can transfer a certain sum into my account they will unlock it, upon which I will of course pay your bills and throw in a handsome bonus.

Comment: +2 because I'm bad at math

Comment: +½; your other half is in the mail

Comment: +1 because I like the little guy besides your name (reminds of the Reputation Bordello :) ).

Answer (score 5):

People can vote however they want, for whatever reason they want. After all, everyone only gets one vote and vote abuse is automatically handled.

Beyond that fact, this seems much like a humorous comment than anything else.